# Run Jar Files in PATH

Tags: java, jar, path, windows-10

I store jar files in C:\Users\myuser\javatools\avro-tools

And added them to my PATH:

```
echo %PATH%
...;
C:\Users\myuser\javatools\avro-tools;
```

I can run them by specifying the full path:

```
java -jar C:\Users\myuser\javatools\avro-tools\avro-tools-1.8.1.jar
```

But cannot run them without the full path:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile avro-tools-1.8.1.jar
```

I need to run jar files without changing to the directory, nor specifying these full paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE***: Added `%*`

I'd recommend creating a batch file and run that instead.

**avro-tools-1.8.1.bat**

```
@echo off
java -jar C:\Users\myuser\javatools\avro-tools\avro-tools-1.8.1.jar %*
```

Place `.bat` file somewhere in PATH, and run by simply typing:

```
avro-tools-1.8.1.bat -abc def
```

The `%*` in the `.bat` file gets replaced with any argument passed to the `.bat` file, so the `-abc def` arguments are passed to the `avro-tools` program in the `args` array to the `main` method.

---

If you have multiple versions of Java installed, you can then choose which one to use when running that `.jar` file, by also qualifying the `java` command.

**avro-tools-1.8.1.bat**

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\java.exe" -jar C:\Users\myuser\javatools\avro-tools\avro-tools-1.8.1.jar %*
```

Now that code will run with Java 8, even if Java 8 is not the default Java on your machine.

Comment: This almost works. The issue is avro-tools.1.8.1.jar has multiple tools and the full command I want to make is: `java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar compile -string schema path/to/schema.avsc path/to/output/classes`. But a .bat file ignores these additional arguments, and it would defeat the purpose to have to specify them inside the bat file every time.

Comment: @Wassadamo Add `%*` to the end of the .bat file’s second line.  That will be replaced with any arguments given to the .bat file.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Any idea why jar files don't seem to be recognized on path while .bat files are?

Comment: @Wassadamo Because Windows wasn't configured for that. You can configure it though. Try asking on https://superuser.com/ for how to do that.